# Laravel vue infinite scroll won't pull new data

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using element UI and it has [infinite scroll](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/infiniteScroll#disable-loading) with it, but i can't get it to work in my app.

## Code

`script`

```
data() {
    return {
        count: '', // default is 8
        total: '', // defalt is 15
        perPage: '', // default is 8
        loading: false,
        products: [],
    }
},
computed: {
    noMore () {
        return this.count >= this.total // if this.count (8) reach this.total (15) then show no more text.
    },
    disabled () {
        return this.loading || this.noMore
    }
},
methods: {
    load () {
        this.loading = true
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.count += this.perPage // add 8 more to page
            this.loading = false
        }, 1000)
    },
    getProducts: function(){
        axios.get('/api/products').then(response => {
            this.products = response.data.data;

            this.count = response.data.meta.per_page; // set count to 8 (backend based)
            this.perPage = response.data.meta.per_page; // set perPage to 8 (backend based)
            this.total = response.data.meta.total; // my testing data are 15 so it sets total to 15 (backend based)
        }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.getProducts();
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="row mt-5 my-5 infinite-list" v-infinite-scroll="load" infinite-scroll-disabled="disabled"> // load function
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3" v-for="product in products" :key="product.slug" :offset="1"> // loop function
        <el-card shadow="hover" :body-style="{ padding: '0px' }">
            {{product.name}}
        </el-card>
    </div>

    // infinite functions
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3" v-if="loading">
        <el-card shadow="always" class="text-center">Loading...</el-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3" v-if="noMore">
        <el-card shadow="always" class="text-center">That's it, No more!</el-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Meta data`

[image: two]

`Result`

[image: one]

**What did I do wrong in my code?**

Answer (score 0):

its because of  your load function take look on it,

```
 load () {
    this.loading = true
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.count += this.perPage // add 8 more to page
        this.loading = false
    }, 1000)
  },
```

you have set time out for 1000 ms which is called after each scroll
first count is updated by fetch call and then second time its updated by time out call back of load function ,
instead of making this.loading =false after 1000 ms you should make it false on success of fetch call and same thing apply for updating this.count, hope this will help you.

**EDIT:**

your load function should be like following

```
load () {
this.loading = true
this.getProducts();//previously you getproduct is called once only after mounted,you you need to call it each time whenever load is called
},
```

and you fetch function should be like

```
getProducts: function(){
    axios.get('/api/products').then(response => {
        this.products = response.data.data;
        this.count += this.perPage // add 8 more to page
    this.loading = false
        this.perPage = response.data.meta.per_page; // set perPage to 8 (backend based)
        this.total = response.data.meta.total; // my testing data are 15 so it sets total to 15 (backend based)
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

another thing you can try is ,use getProducts instead of load and remove load function, make this.loading=true in your getProducts function,
previously your getProducts  is called only once when component is mounted.you need to call getProducts function each time whenever load more is requested.

Comment: so what should i change now? increase `1000 ms` or moving `false` to other location?

Comment: @mafortis i have updated my answer ,please check it

Comment: @mafortis can you specify the problem?i think it should work,can you provide any fiddle?

Comment: the problem is i don't get new data

Comment: on js fiddle api call is not getting data(blocked by client),so its going to error callback and this.loading stuck to true.

Comment: obviously it's not going to get any data my app is in localhost:/  the propose of fiddle was for you to see how current code looks like not to get data :)